# Reproject XYZ tile layer on the fly in Openlayers 3?

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers, epsg

I have an Openlayers 3 application which has a default map projection of EPSG:27700 with both base layers and WFS layers using the same system as well as various mapping tools like measuring options.

I would like to add a base map layer which uses the Web Mercator (EPSG:3857) projection - after adding the layer as a new tile service, it does appear but there is a shift in where it sits on the map (due to the difference in coordinate system).

My question is, am I able to reproject this Web Mercator layer on the fly, without having to change my view projection?

I have provided a fiddle to a working example below - if you zoom right down to building level you will notice an approx 15 metre shift between base maps (https://jsfiddle.net/1bayd0ps/).

Comment: Tile should be reprojected automatically to the projection of your `view` . Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: @pavlos Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1bayd0ps/

Comment: Hi this is correct. You use basemaps from different sources. Do not expect to fit 100%. The same think would happen if you were using Google maps , or any other different source. Your reprojection is fine. You cannt do much about the shifting.

Comment: @pavlos Ok, I just expected a similar result as I get in QGIS - the same approach fits both base maps exactly on top of each other.

Comment: Do you use the same projection for your map in QGIS?

Comment: @pavlos Yes, my map is EPSG:27700 and I bring in EPSG:3857 maps using the QuickMapService plugin - they reproject on the fly.

Comment: Maybe the use different engines to do the reprojection, Or maybe I am missing something.

Comment: @pavlos I have found this example which manages to overlay the tiles exactly, this looks to require the closure library and goog require? http://www.bdcc.co.uk/ol3/examples/warped-tiles2.html

Comment: I think this is based in a very old verison of ol. 3.1 or something. By that time tile reprojection was not an option for ol3. Also the example reproject tiles on `EPSG:3857` you may try it that way. Reproject OS tiles in `EPSG:3857`

Comment: @pavlos Unfortunately my application needs to be in EPSG:27700 as my tools use British National Grid coordinates. This example does overlay the base maps exactly though, so although old it does seem to reproject much more accurately?